# Add specific special characters parenthesis ( ) in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently, I have this regex for telephone number

```
/^\+?\d+(-\d+)*$/
```

which allows:

```
123
123-456
123-456-789
```

I'm aiming to also accept parenthesis in my regex ( )
for example:

```
(02)123-456
```

How can I do it with my current regex?

Comment: you should escape them

Comment: Just add an optional group, like `/^\+?(?:\(\d+\))?\d+(-\d+)*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Add/Append `(\(\d+\))?` in front of `/^\+?\d+(-\d+)*$/`

If you need min. 2 numbers, use this `(\(\d{2,}\))?`

Basically, you need to escape the `()`, remember that in almost any language you would do it with the `\`-character. From then on you only need to specify the number of occurrences.